# How do you access one repeater's control into another repeater's OnItemCommand() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

lets say I want to make a label of repeater1 visible in repater2's ItemCommand() method..

```
e.Item.FindControl("rpt1Label").Visible=True;
```

is not working..how else do you do it ?

[EDIT]

changed that to `repeater1.FindControl("rpt1Label").Visible=True;`

This is throwing object reference null exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**inside the repeater (normal way to do it for a repeater):**

```
Label thisLabel = (Label)e.item.findcontrol("rpt1Label");

if(thislabel != null 
{
   thislabel.visible = true;
}
```

**if you have a 2nd repeater nested in your first repeater:**

```
Repeater thisRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repeaterName");
Label thisLabel = (Label)thisRepeater.findcontrol("rpt1Label"); 

if(thislabel != null  
{ 
   thislabel.visible = true; 
}
```

Normally it should just be possible to acces the repeater1 from repeater2 by accessing:

```
(Label) thisLabel = (Label)this.repeater1.findcontrol("labelname");
```